# File downloaded by CURL in C++ cannot be opened

Tags: c++, curl, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm working upon a program in `C++`, where I have to download a file using `cURL`, and further open it, but the problem is that when I try to open the file after downloading, it isn't opening. I'm trying to open an `.exe` file. Here's the portion of code, which is responsible for file download

```
curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename.c_str(), "w");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, links[index]);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
```

and the line which should open the downloaded file :

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", fileToLaunch.c_str() , NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE);
```

When I try to launch manually the file (by clicking on it), `Windows` returns me an error message which says that respective app isn't a `Win32` app. I'm using `Visual Studio 2017`.

Here's the whole chunk of code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    string url = "Here goes the url for file download";
    string outfilename = "C:\\1.exe";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename.c_str(), "wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;

    ShellExecute(NULL, "open", outfilename.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE);
}
```

Comment: Does the value of `res` make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this line should be deleted :

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
```

because `write_data` function has the same functionality, as cURL's `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`, and so, the line below the one which should be deleted will be enough, and secondly, on the line where `curl_easy_setopt()` is firstly met:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
```

you should add to the `url` parameter `.c_str()`, so it will look like this :

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```

because this function is unable to operate with string type of data...

And as `Rob K` mentioned, you have to change `'w'` to `'wb'` in `fopen()` function, because you are working with a binary stream of data.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
fp = fopen(outfilename.c_str(), "w");
```

to

```
fp = fopen(outfilename.c_str(), "wb");
```

You're writing it to disk as text with newline translations by default. You need to write it as binary.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2017 for a fuller explanation.

Comment: I tried with `wb` too, but the problem still persists

Comment: Can you add an [mcve], especially the code for `write_data()`? Calling `fopen()` without the 'b' is the one obvious flaw in the code you posted.

Comment: I've added the desired example

Comment: Did you look at the *contents* of the downloaded file to make sure it is what you are expecting, and not something else, like maybe a server error page?